# Vuex: [vuex] module namespace not found in mapState() | mapGetters(): X/

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Following from the Vuex documentation for organising the store modularly (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html), I have the following in:

`store/index.js`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

// Default Store State for the Hug Employee Dashboard:
// import defaultState from "@/store/defaultStore";

/*eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": false }]*/
/*eslint indent: ["error", 2]*/
/*eslint arrow-body-style: ["error", "always"]*/
/*eslint-env es6*/

const surfGroups = {
  state: {
    activeSurfGroup: {},
    fetchingSurfGroupLoading: false,
    creatingSurfGroupLoading: false
  },
  getters: {
    activeSurfGroup: state => {
      return state.activeSurfGroup;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    // API Request Mutations:
    SET_ACTIVE_SURF_GROUP(state, payload) {
      this.activeSurfGroup = payload;
    },
    // Loading Mutations:
    SET_FETCHING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING(state, payload) {
      state.fetchingSurfGroupLoading = payload;
    },
    SET_CREATING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING(state, payload) {
      state.creatingSurfGroupsLoading = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchSurfGroup: async ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit("SET_FETCHING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING", true);
      // Dispatches the following Surf Levels API service:
      // this.$surfLevelsAPI.fetchActiveSurfGroup(
      //   payload.activeSurfGroupUUID
      // );
      await Vue.prototype.$surfLevelsAPI.fetchActiveSurfGroup(payload).then((response) => {
        if (response.success) {
          commit("SET_ACTIVE_SURF_GROUP", response.data);
          commit("SET_FETCHING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING", false);
        }
      });
    },
    createSurfGroup: async ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit("SET_CREATING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING", true);
      // Dispatches the following Surf Levels API service:
      // this.$surfLevelsAPI.createNewSurfGroup(
      //   payload.activeSurfInstructor, payload.activeSurfSessionSelected, payload.activeGroupSurfers
      // );
      await Vue.prototype.$surfLevelsAPI.createNewSurfGroup(payload).then((response) => {
        if (response.success) {
          commit("SET_CREATING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING", false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    surfGroups: surfGroups
  }
});
```

I feel like this all looks good.

However, within `component.Vue`, when I ...mapState as:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  // Computed Properties:
  computed: {
    ...mapState('surfGroups', [
      'creatingSurfGroupLoading',
    ]),
  },
  // Component Watchers:
  watch: {
    creatingSurfGroupLoading() {
      console.log(this.creatingSurfGroupLoading);
    },
  },
};
```

I receive the following error:

`[vuex] module namespace not found in mapState(): surfGroups/`

What exactly have I done wrong? I can see any obvious descrepancies from reading through the docs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You haven't set namespace.

```
const surfGroups = {
  namespaced: true,
...
```

Source: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't think it is your fault but it's now not erroring but the state is not mapping unfortunately.

Comment: Scrap that, I had a type. Thanks @artoju!

Answer (score 2):

This is an indication, that from somewhere of your app, you are calling:

```
mapState("XYZ..")  
//or
magGetters("XYZ..")
//or
this.$store.dispatch('XYZ/myFunc'...
this.$store.commit('XYZ/myFunc'...
```

while you haven't defined the Store's module `XYZ` as "namespaced". To do that, in the  module export, add the `namespaced:true`:

```
//XYZ.js

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    ...
    getters:{
        myFunc: state => {
            return "HELLO";
       }
    }
    mutations,
    actions,
};
```

So, no change is needed inside `Vuex.Store({..})` directly. It will automatically recognize that module as `namespaced`.

---

p.s. also check if your namespace key name declared in `Vuex.Store()` creation, is correct, like:

```
Vuex.Store({
    modules:{
       abc: XYZ   <---- i.e. key name should be `XYZ` , that matters mostly.
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
   modules: { userstore },
   state: {},
   mutations: {},
   actions: {},
   modules: {},
});
```

maybe you have two modules like this and the last one replaces the first one.